# Spring boot REST webservice returns 404 when deployed to azure

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, azure

I just created a spring boot rest webservice using the following tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

The application is supposed to return a JSON response upon visting http://localhost:8080/greeting

It runs fine locally. However, upon deployment to azure it doesn't give me any response, just a blank screen. When i inspect the page, it says under network there is a 404  error.

Am i missing something?

EDIT:

I solved the issue by adding a web.config file in the /wwwroot folder.

Comment: have you deployed this to a web app, or to a VM?

Comment: it's deployed as a web-app

Comment: did you package it as a war and push it under webapps?

Comment: Yes i did. I have tried including the .war name in the URL. For example: http://<name>.azurewebsites.net/<.war name>/greeting, however still no response

Comment: Can you use the kudu debug console to check that the .war and the <warname> folder are under the site\wwwroot\webapps .  Also what is the Java and Tomcat version selected?

Comment: The path of the .war file = D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\restAPI-test-0.1.0>. In azure settings the java version = 8 and tomcat version = newest 8.0.